# how to read an integer from the end of a txt file?

Tags: c, file

the file contains a 1/2/3-digit integer at the end. How can I scan only the number?

an (maybe) important thing: the character one before the number is '`' or any other char I will decide. If it doesn't help I can omit it.

if this is my file:

...

*jhgcfxdfghjkl*

*avav dfvfbrjykuyi*

*ma halooz evrbetj*

*`99*

```
       ...

    int index = 0;
    FILE* fpointer = fopen(file_name, "a+"); 
    if (!fpointer) {
        printf("\nFILE ERROR.");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
        {
            fseek(fpointer, i, SEEK_END);
            if (fscanf(fpointer, "%d") != 0)
            {
                fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &index); // why does it enter this line even though the number is 1-digit?
                break;
            }
        }
```

---

So I've tried this. The for loop is supposed to check wether the character-`i`-before-the-number is an integer- but however, even though the number is only 1-digit, it enters the line as if the condition is being met. What do I miss?

Comment: "even though the number is only 1-digit, it enters the line" I don't understand what you don't understand there. A 1-digit number is a number.

Comment: but I moved the pointer to 3 places from end (with `fseek`)

Comment: but doesn't `fseek` move the pointer to `i`- places **before** the end?

Comment: And if it isn't equal to 1 what can be the reason? [that's my problem now :(  ] Or can I read it and scan it using another function? because I didn't find one that does it directly.

Comment: No. There is no newline.  
And thank you really much for helping.

Comment: Why don't you: 1) `fseek` at `i=-4` from `SEEK_END`, 2) Advance until you find your _guard char_ (`'`), 3) if it was found (and not in the last position) read all the remaining data with `fscanf` or with `fread` + `atoi`

Comment: @Roberto Caboni   That's simple **and** works.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. Just a warning: unless you are sure it **cannot** happen, watch out the side case in which more than a guard char is present at the end of the file. For example `'a'5`